# Hibernate embeddable list

Tags: java, hibernate, embeddable

I have two ready tables:

```
Table "One"
id numeric (PK);
name varchar(100); 

Table "Two"
property1 varchar(100);
one_id long;
```

I want map two classes for it tables:

```
class One 
{
long id;
String name;
}

Two
{
  One parent;
  String property1;
}
```

If I add `List<Two> properties` into One class, what annotations I must add to it? Class 'Two' marks as  Embeddable. Modification of tables is deprecated.

Comment: you want to add full table Two in table One. Please clarify that

Comment: `Class 'Two' marks as Embeddable.` -- means?

Comment: I want save some entities without primary key via hibernate. 
At this structure (if its possible) - I want save "One" with all elements of collection "Two".

Comment: >> Class 'Two' marks as Embeddable. -- means? 
Because PK not available - single way to use it- marks as @Embeddable. Or I incorrect understand it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a class Two at all. What you need in class One is

```
@ElementCollection
@Column(name = "property1")
@JoinColumn(name = "one_id")
private Set<String> properties;
```

Comment: class Two - is a small example of production version. Real class contains more than one field

Comment: Then annotate it with `@Embeddable`, use a `Set<Two>` instead of a `Set<String>`, and remove the `@Column` annotation. Your Two class may not have a field of type `One`.

Comment: Sql output show incorrect column name during insert records into "Two" table: insert into Two (Two_id, property1) values (?, ?)

Comment: I solve probjem with adding @CollectionTable(name="Two", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "one_id"))

and remove field parent from Two